# Simple C++ undefined reference error during linking while using a class

Tags: c++, class, g++, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I've got a simple problem I think. But I am unable to solve it so far as I am new to C++ programming. I have created a new C++ project to make the code as short and simple as possible (because the original code is much much longer) while keeping the problem I have. I have searched on Stackoverflow and Google and read about 50 related problems but nothing so far helped me fix it. Putting everything in one cc and one h file works, but is not what I prefer doing. Thanks in advance for the help.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 / Code::Blocks 13.12 / gcc and g++ 4.8.2

The problem is that I want to access the function inside a class defined in a different file and while compiling works (due to the extern in file1.h) linking fails. If I just put "Simple S1;" instead of "extern Simple S1;" in file1.h and remove it from file1.cc I get a multiple declaration error which is expected. Apparently the "extern" trick doesn't work with classes while it works great with variables.

file1.h:

```
#ifndef FILE1_H
#define FILE1_H

class Simple
{
    private:
    unsigned int length = 10;

    public:
    void SetLength(unsigned int l) {length = l;}
    unsigned int GetLength() {return length;}
};

extern Simple S1;

#endif
```

file1.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

int main()
{
    Simple S1;
    unsigned int l = GetL();
    std::cout << "length=" << l << "\n";
    l = 20;
    l = GetL();
    std::cout << "length=" << l << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

file2.h:

```
#ifndef FILE2_H
#define FILE2_H

unsigned int GetL();

#endif
```

file2.cc:

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

unsigned int GetL()
{
    return S1.GetLength();
}
```

build commands and error:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c file1.cc -o obj/Debug/file1.o
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c file2.cc -o obj/Debug/file2.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/Test obj/Debug/file1.o obj/Debug/file2.o   
obj/Debug/file2.o: In function `GetL()':
file2.cc:6: undefined reference to `S1'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If S1 is global it must be defined at global scope, not inside main() which creates a new instance local to that function.

Put `Simple S1;` before main() in your function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

Simple S1;

int main()
{
    unsigned int l = GetL();
    std::cout << "length=" << l << "\n";
    l = 20;
    l = GetL();
    std::cout << "length=" << l << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you too for the incredible fast and correct response, I was so focused on the whole class thing which I just added to the code that I failed to see something this obvious.

Comment: And I was about a minute ahead of the other answer but you accpeted the other one..

Comment: Sorry I didn't look at that, it just listed the other one first after I checked my question. Did not think I would receive an answer that fast wow. Corrected accepted answer though I would prefer to give you both credits.

Comment: Of course an alternative would be to have `GetL()` accept the object it works on:  `unsigned int GetL(simple S1){return S1.GetLength();}` and call it with `l=GetL(S1);`

Comment: The question is asking how to link in a global. I assume the question is simplified.

Answer (score 0):

```
extern Simple S1;
```

This declaration promises there is a global object `S1` of type `Simple` somewhere else in the code. But you never define such an object. The "closest" you come to that is the local variable `S1` inside `main()`, but of course, that's an entirely different things.

So just move the definition of `S1` outside of `main()`:

```
Simple S1;

int main()
{
    unsigned int l = GetL();
    std::cout << "length=" << l << "\n";
    l = 20;
    l = GetL();
    std::cout << "length=" << l << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the incredible fast and correct response, I was so focused on the whole class thing which I just added to the code that I failed to see something this obvious.